# Sahi with TLS1.1

Tags: automation, handshake, sslhandshakeexception, sahi, tls1.2

Sahi OS V5.0 throws a Handshake failure exception after the application server being upgraded to TLS1.1. Using the sahi driver, I'm not able to navigate to any url's of this upgraded server. But the older one works fine.

Does anyone know how to configure this?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)

at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)

at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)

at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)

at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)

at net.sf.sahi.RemoteRequestProcessor.processHttp(RemoteRequestProcessor.java:151)........
```

Comment: Try passing this flag while launching sahi: -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=true

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently not sure how Sahi OS 5 does it, but we changed the SSL implementation in the code and changed the parameters in the browser.xml to prevent phantomjs from using SSLv3

Have a look at https://github.com/headissue/Sahi/commit/84c45f99f920893a7dfd39e2565819afd91c858e for reference and have a look at your browsers, if they still use SSLv3

Regards
globalworming

Answer (score 0):

Two things fixed this issue:

1. Passing an argument to JVM to set the version of TLS to be used.

> -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1

2. Using the Java of same version in both client and server.